# Difference between i+1<vec.size() and i<vec.size()-1 in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

My C++ code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long
#define test() ll t; cin>>t; while(t--)

int main ()
{
    test()
    {
        ll n,c,i;
        cin>>n>>c;

        string s;
        cin>>s;

        vector<ll>position;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(s[i]=='1')
                position.push_back(i);
        }

      
            ll cnt=0;
            for(i=0;i<position.size()-1;i++) 
            {
                if((position[i+1]-position[i])-1>c)
                    cnt++;
                
            }
            if(!position.empty() and n-position.back()-1+position[0]>c)
            cnt++;

            if(cnt<=1)
            cout<<"YES\n";
            else 
            cout<<"NO\n";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

i am getting runtime time error, while writing **i<position.size()-1** i am getting RE (SIGSEGV)[runtime error] on codechef

```
for(i=0;i<position.size()-1;i++) 
{
    if((position[i+1]-position[i])-1>c)
       cnt++;
}
```

but if i am writing **i+1<position.size()-1** i am getting AC(All correct)

```
for(i=0;i+1<position.size();i++) 
{
    if((position[i+1]-position[i])-1>c)
       cnt++;
}
```

please tell me what is the reason for this and why this is happening

Comment: `position.size()` may be zero. Have you checked this?

Comment: I beleive `size()` is unsigned.

Comment: If `x` is an unsigned zero, `x-1` is the maximum value of whatever type `x` has.

Comment: if position.size() is zero then in both cases the loop will not run  because `for(i=0;0<-1;i++)` and in second 'for(i=0;1<0;i++)` in both the cases loop will not run

Comment: @Shivamkumar No, because the size is unsigned. Take a look [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/176b8cdd7f5b41cc).

Comment: Note that, if instructed, your compiler may helpfully [warn you](https://godbolt.org/z/ExKcEx387).